# How would you providing routing for directions between points on a map? What are the missing pieces?

Tags: routes, maps, directions, ios6

With iOS 6 the Maps app is dropping Google Maps. The terms of the Google Maps SDK states that if you plot directions with their service you must show it on their map. Since this will no longer be the case I need to explore other options to get directions and display routes on a map.

I have found that MapQuest and Nokia each offer an API to provide direction and routing services.

1. MapQuest - http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/
2. Nokia - http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.0/symbols/nokia.maps.routing.html

I also see OpenStreetMap has a list of online routing services with varying levels of support for various locations and some are in pre-release state.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers

I have not done much with routing before I would like to find a primer on mapping software that covers the basics. A big question I have is for curves in routes. I only know about coordinates for maps. I am not aware of a way to define a route along a curve, unless that means using a lot of coordinates to draw the curve. I'd appreciation some explanation of what to do for curves. An option for known routes such as roads as well as sidewalks and walking paths would be ideal. A basic primer on plotting directions along known routes would be most helpful.

All help is appreciated. I know lots of developers preparing apps for iOS 6 will be looking into services for directions and routes and I hope the information gathered with this question will help provide a starting point for them.

Comment: OpenStreetMaps has multiple books available: http://amzn.to/N2QKki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MapQuest iOS Maps API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api) includes routing functionality.  It might be worth a look?

MapQuest also offers a [JavaScript API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/javascript) (which supports mobile devices) and [Mobile Flash API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash-mobile) (using the Flex SDK to create native iOS and Android apps) as well, which are essentially wrappers for the core [MapQuest Web Services](http://www.mapquestapi.com), including the Directions service that you already mentioned.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Please disclose in your answers your affiliation with MapQuest. Several of these have been marked as spam by the community, and you can help avoid that by properly stating that you work for the company in question.

Comment: Ok, will do -- yes, I work for MapQuest.  Not trying to be misleading -- just trying to be helpful by letting everyone know that MapQuest offers a few options as well.

Comment: I do not think it is misleading when MapQuest is one of the few services offering routing services unlike Apple, Yahoo or other mapping services.